# replacing the column of values from next file column values by matching text

Tags: linux, bash, awk

My question is simple I have two files first having list of values and text like

```
  NA   NPH1   0.210000 
  NB   NPH2  -0.146000 
  NC   NPH3   0.179000
  ND   NPH4  -0.130000
```

and the second file has format

```
                  column 1      column 2 

   5 O1   139  BCL  ND   NPH4  -0.130000       14.0070           0
   6 O1   139  BCL  C1A  CPAN   0.031000       12.0110           0
   7 O1   139  BCL  CHA  CPM2  -0.163000       12.0110           0
   8 O1   139  BCL  C4D  CPA3  -0.007000       12.0110           0
   9 O1   139  BCL  C1B  CPAN  -0.231000       12.0110           0
  10 O1   139  BCL  CHB  CPMN  -0.317000       12.0110           0
```

I want to replace the column 2 values by matching column 1 text from file 1 (for eg: NA = NA) then replace the value in column 2.

The second problem is the file 2 has also some other sections I would like copy and make a new file after replacing.

The other sections begin with 
 11940 !NBOND: bonds and I want to copy till the end of the file

Comment: Glad your question is simple. Wouldn't want to ask something complicated of the folks here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want this:

File1:

```
NA NPH1,0.210000 
NB NPH2,0.146000 
NC NPH3,0.179000
ND NPH4,-0.130000
```

(For readability, I am replacing what I assume is an invisible tab with a ",")

File2:

```
5 O1 139 BCL,ND NPH4,-0.123456,14.0070,0
6 O1 139 BCL,C1A CPAN,0.031000,12.0110,0
7 O1 139 BCL,CHA CPM2,-0.163000,12.0110,0
```

Output:

```
5 O1 139 BCL,ND NPH4,-0.130000,14.0070,0
6 O1 139 BCL,C1A CPAN,0.031000,12.0110,0
7 O1 139 BCL,CHA CPM2,-0.163000,12.0110,0
```

I would do something like this in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(F,"< file1") || die;
while(<F>) {
        chop;
        s/^\s*//;
        @l = split(/,/);
        $subs{$l[0]} = $l[1]
}
close(F);
open(F,"< file2") || die;
while(<F>) {
        s/^\s*//;
        @l = split(/,/);
        if($subs{$l[1]}) {
                $l[2] = $subs{$l[1]};
        }
        print join(',',@l);
}
```

Comment: I have columns with thousands of lines its hard to add or remove using comma. Please give a suggestion to reading the spaces. so that i don't end up in messing up with file order

Comment: sorry i think you understood the question wrongly, The NB should match with NB of file 2 then replace the values. i think you understood the problem wrongly. your code just replaces the column text its not matching the text and replacing it